# How to integrate Elasticsearch for Realtime Visualization?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, elastic-stack, real-time-data

I am trying to visualize my data which is in `elasticsearch` and using `Kibana5` for that.
But the problem is what `Kibana` visualizes is not realtime visualization. If I update my data then I need to visualize that again and need to reflect on my dashboard, but this is not what I am looking for.

This particular problem I am facing while I am trying to embed the iframe with some `PHP` script.

I want to know how I can automate the process? How I can make the visualization real time and also do not want to interfere many times?

Kindly suggest me what is the possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Kibana5` will constantly listen to the elastic search according to the refresh interval.So set refresh interval to a minimum value (around 5 sec) so that kibana will be update in every 5 seconds

Comment: I am facing this issue while I am trying to embed the iframe and it is not taking the updated data counts.